# Since Proxima Centauri orbits the other two Alpha Centauri stars, will it eventually be farther away from us than they are?

Tags: star, distances, nomenclature

And, if so, will we have to change its name to Distal Centauri ;-) ?

Granted, its orbital period around the other two is about 550,000 Earth years, so we have some time....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In about 26,000 years, Proxima Centauri will no longer be the closest star. Instead, Alpha Centauri AB will be the closest, but only for about ~7000 years, soon replaced by Ross 248 for 10000 years, and Gliese 445 for 6000 years. Then, Alpha Centauri will continue to be the nearest star for another ~28000 years, then briefly becoming Ross 128. Refer to the diagram below (sourced from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs#/media/File:Near-stars-past-future-en.svg)).

[image: star distances]

Correct me if I'm wrong, and feel free to edit my answer if it needs improvement.

Comment: The plot is out of date (thanks to Gaia), though your conclusions may still be correct.